# cuda kernel - registers

Tags: cuda

Float4 variables defined in the kernel should be store in registers !? I made a simple test. In the first kernel I use registers to optimize a memory traffic, in the second I read directly from a global memory.

```
__global__ void kernel(float4 *arg1, float4 *arg2, float4 *arg3)
{
     int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

     float4 temp1 = arg2[x];
     float4 temp2 = arg3[x];
     //some computations using temp1 and temp2
     arg2[x] = temp1;
     arg3[x] = temp2;

     arg1[x] = make_float4(temp1.x, temp1.y, temp1.z, temp1.w);
}



 __global__ void kernel(float4 *arg1, float4 *arg2, float4 *arg3)
{
     int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
     //some computations using a direct access to global memory
     //for example arg2[x].x
     arg1[x] = make_float4(arg2[x].x, arg2[x].y, arg2[x].z, arg2[x].w);
}
```

The first kernel is 9-10% faster. The difference in not so big. When using registers can bring more benefits ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can't say what will and won't be in registers solely based on C code. That is certainly not the the source of the performance difference between the two codes. In fact, both kernels use registers for the float4 variables, and the code they compile to is almost identical.

First kernel:

```
ld.param.u64    %rd3, [__cudaparm__Z7kernel0P6float4S0_S0__arg2];
add.u64         %rd4, %rd3, %rd2;
ld.global.v4.f32        {%f1,%f2,%f3,%f4}, [%rd4+0];
.loc    16      21      0
ld.param.u64    %rd5, [__cudaparm__Z7kernel0P6float4S0_S0__arg3];
add.u64         %rd6, %rd5, %rd2;
ld.global.v4.f32        {%f5,%f6,%f7,%f8}, [%rd6+0];
st.global.v4.f32        [%rd4+0], {%f1,%f2,%f3,%f4};
st.global.v4.f32        [%rd6+0], {%f5,%f6,%f7,%f8};
.loc    16      24      0
ld.param.u64    %rd7, [__cudaparm__Z7kernel0P6float4S0_S0__arg1];
add.u64         %rd8, %rd7, %rd2;
st.global.v4.f32        [%rd8+0], {%f1,%f2,%f3,%f4};
```

second kernel:

```
ld.param.u64    %rd3, [__cudaparm__Z7kernel1P6float4S0_S0__arg2];
add.u64         %rd4, %rd3, %rd2;
ld.global.v4.f32        {%f1,%f2,%f3,%f4}, [%rd4+0];
ld.param.u64    %rd5, [__cudaparm__Z7kernel1P6float4S0_S0__arg1];
add.u64         %rd6, %rd5, %rd2;
st.global.v4.f32        [%rd6+0], {%f1,%f2,%f3,%f4};
```

If there really is a performance difference between them, it is probably that the first kernel has more opportunity for instruction level parallelism than the second. But that is just a wild guess, without knowing much more about how the benchmarking of the two was done.

Comment: cuMemcpyHtoD send the data to the global device memory. The first argument in the kernel is vertex buffer object. Computations in kernels are exactly the same. The only difference is how kernel reads and wirtes to the memory. The difference between them refers to fps. int x and float 4 variables are store in registers, right ?  So the difference is caused by memory latency, registers are faster. for example this read and write to registers: temp1.x += temp2.x; this read and write to global device memory arg2[x].x += arg3[x].x

Comment: I agree that we can't tell which is kept in registers by using C code. Why don't you just profile it (register_per_thread and other statistic information)? It will be much clearer. In your case, I suspect cache usage is the source of difference.